# wordpress vs solr for search

Tags: php, wordpress, solr

In SOLR when the DB is updated with new columns that need to be searched we have to update the data-config file to reflect those changes. We are considering moving to a wordpress platform and have the option of using the native search or solr.

If I add a new column to a table I have to update data-config queries to include the new column for search. What is the code change (if any) required to do the same using native wordpress search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [WordPress 3.7](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7394), search relevance works as follows:

- Full sentence matches in post titles.
- All search terms in post titles.
- Any search terms in post titles.
- Full sentence matches in post content.

Each section and any remaining posts are then sorted by date.

WordPress' built-in search is not anywhere near as powerful as SOLR, but with WordPress, the database is searched on the fly without the need to change any code (as so long as you are searching the normal WordPress database tables).

The built-in search is known to be quite clunky, and is not recommended for large sites. [WordPress VIP offers clients ElasticSearch](http://vip.wordpress.com/vip-search-add-on/), which I highly recommend (the [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) part, not the VIP part), if you do move to WordPress. There are also other third-party solutions, like [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) for small sites that don't have lots of post data.

Hope this helps.